# How to map a character to IE/Mozilla keycodes to use with Javascript keyup events?

Tags: javascript, events, keyboard-events, keycode

I'm trying to get the Mozilla/IE keycode for a arbitrary character in Javascript.  Ideally, I'd use charCodeAt() to retrieve the keycode for a given character, but this yields the ASCII value which is useless for the keyup listener.

For example: `']'.charCodeAt()` returns 93, but event.keyCode and event.which = 221

Answer (score 0):

The mapping between key codes and the characters produced by those keys is dependent on keyboard layout, which varies significantly worldwide. Also, there are often many different combinations of keystrokes that can produce the same character. That being the case, there is no dependable way of mapping key codes to characters and vice versa.

Bottom line: if you need to detect a particular typed character, only the `keypress` event will do. If you want to detect physical keystrokes, only `keyup` and `keydown` will do.

Comment: I'm probably not fully understanding the intent of the `keydown` and `keyup` events, but it doesn't seem to be such a stretch to include the ASCII code in the event object.  So it looks like the best we can do is to record the typed character on `keypress` and verify on `keyup` that recorded character matches the charcode we're interested in.